# how define condition that ends while loop iteration of python list?

Tags: python, while-loop

I am having trouble with this Python practice problem:

> Write a function, sublist, that takes in a list of numbers as the parameter. In the function, use a while loop to return a sublist of the input list. The sublist should contain the same values of the original list up until it reaches the number 5 (it should not contain the number 5).

Here is my attempt but `is_valid` never gets set to `False`.

```
def sublist(lst):
  is_valid = True 
  ret_lst = [] 
  while is_valid:
    for x in lst:
      print(x, is_valid)
      if x == 5:
        is_valid == False
      else:
        ret_lst.append(x)

  return ret_lst

lst = [1,2,3,4,5]
print(sublist(lst))
```

After reading the comments I rewrote the function as:

```
def sublist(lst):
  ret_lst = []
  i = 0; 
  while i < len(lst):
    if lst[i] != 5:
      ret_lst.append(lst[i])
      i += 1
    else:
      break
  return ret_lst

lst = [1,2,3,4,5,7,9]
print(sublist(lst))
```

Comment: You want `is_valid = False`. `==` is for comparisons; it doesn't assign. Voting to close as a typo.

Comment: @Carcigenicate he has two loops, the break command would only break out of his for loop.

Comment: @Carcigenicate All good, I was thinking about how to use a break command too, perhaps if he only needed one for loop the break command would be best.

Comment: FWIW, there's no need to use a `while` loop for this. `def sublist(lst): return lst[:lst.index(5)]`

Comment: @wjandrea: Or with a single pass (but requiring an import): `return list(itertools.takewhile(lambda x: x != 5, lst))`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [@Enthus3d](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12014856/enthus3d) has noted, `is_valid == False` compares `is_valid` to `False`. What you're trying to do is assign a value to `is_valid`, which is done using one equals sign.

If all you need to do is exit a loop, however, use of the `break` keyword is easier than creating a boolean and checking it.

`break` will end the innermost loop once encountered by the program.

Comment: Just a small note, in his second example, break is the better choice, but for his previous example, break only breaks through one loop, so his use of a flag is better.

Answer (score 1):

Line 8 of your program,

`is_valid == False`

should be

`is_valid = False`,

since `==` is a comparison operator (to compare if two things are equal), and what you're looking for is the `=` assignment operation (to assign one thing a value) .